# How can I link different tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to connect 3 different Sql tables with left join. You can see my sql code below.

```
$sql = "SELECT o.order_id, cgd.name, CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer_name,
email, telephone, CONCAT(o.payment_firstname, ' ', o.payment_lastname,',',o.payment_address_1,',',o.payment_address_2,',',o.payment_city,'-',o.payment_postcode) AS payment_address,
CONCAT(o.shipping_firstname, ' ', o.shipping_lastname,',',o.shipping_address_1,',',o.shipping_address_2,',', o.shipping_city,'-',o.shipping_postcode) AS shipping_address, prd.product_id, prd.name, prd.model, prd.order_product_id,
o.payment_method, o.shipping_method, prd.total, o.currency_code,o.currency_value,
o.date_added, oos.name as order_status 
FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_group_description cgd ON (o.customer_group_id = cgd.customer_group_id)
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product prd ON (o.order_id = prd.order_id)
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_option mrk ON (o.order_id = mrk.order_id)
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status oos ON (o.order_status_id = oos.order_status_id) WHERE cgd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'";
```

The problem part is order_option table. The table includes NAME and VALUE column. I want to take the VALUE data of NAME column that is Modelno however when i try this for every order it takes VALUE data how much it is.  For instance I have 3 Modelno data and 3 id data, the code gives 9 output.

I tried to remove order_product_id that has the same data with DISTINCT but it was inefficient. How can i fix this?

Comment: Please post sample data and expected results. It would also help if you posted just the SQL, not the PHP wrapper.

Comment: It's hard to tell without more info like fields in each table and sample data. It sounds like maybe you need to JOIN to order_option on two fields... eg order_id AND modelno?